# Generate debug key for facebook integration in Android

Tags: android, facebook-login

I don't know what happened or if it's my fault, but when I ran the command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore | C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe base64
```

The key generated is only 24 characters long, Facebook needs it to be 28 characters long.

The command is from their docs and I couldn't find the error on the internet.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Update OpenSSL to 1.1.0e version and retry, if this doesn't work yet try deleting the debug.keystore and wait for Android Studio to recreate it and try again

Comment: Upgrading to 1.1.0e version solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: No problem, good luck, i will add the comment as answer, so other could find this info usefull, if you want you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update OpenSSL to the current latest version `1.1.0e` downloading it [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate key hash you need to follow some easy steps.

1) Download Openssl from: [here.](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list)

2) Make a **openssl** folder in **C** drive

3) Extract Zip files into this **openssl** folder created in **C** Drive.

4) Copy the File **debug.keystore** from **.android** folder in my case (C:\Users\SYSTEM.android) and paste into JDK bin Folder in my case (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin)

5) **Open command prompt** and give the path of JDK Bin folder in my case (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin).

6) Copy the following code and hit enter

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore >
>   c:\openssl\bin\debug.txt

7) Now you need to **enter password**, Password = android.

8) If you see in **openssl** Bin folder, you will get a file with the name of **debug.txt**

9) Now either you can restart command prompt or work with existing command prompt

10) get back to C drive and **give the path of openssl Bin** folder

11) copy the following code and paste

> openssl sha1 -binary debug.txt > debug_sha.txt

12) you will get **debug_sha.txt** in openssl bin folder

13) Again copy following code and paste

> openssl base64 -in debug_sha.txt > debug_base64.txt

14) you will get **debug_base64.txt** in openssl bin folder

15) open **debug_base64.txt** file Here is your Key hash.

Comment: The problem was the old version of the openssl, thank you for taking the time to help tho